# Slim 3 sites returns 404 in some pages or doesn't load images

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have uploaded my Slim 3 site to my server. Everything works perfectly if I go to
mydomain.com/public.

However, as soon as I add an .htaccess to the root so the user doesn't need to type in "/public" I start getting Page Not Found on some of the pages.  Not in all of them, a lot of the site seems to work just fine, but several pages say "Page Not Found". This only happens in Chrome. In Firefox, Opera and Safari the page loads but the images don't (and not even in the same pages, in some pages the images might load in a browser but not in another).

This is the .htaccess I'm using in the root (different from the .htaccess within public redirecting everything to index.php).

This is the standard .htaccess that goes inside the /public directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And this is what I have in the root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!public)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

I have also tried

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

No matter which I use, the minute I set up the .htaccess to point to /public, the issues start to happen.

I've used this setup for a different site and had no problems at all. Now we are supposed to go live and some pages can't be found.

Comment: Your setup looks quite complex. The file `public/.htaccess` looks ok. Just delete all the other `.htaccess` files and map your Apache DocumentRoot to /var/www/example.com/htdocs/public. Have you tried the [slim-skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton)?